# Big bug in stl? Why does std::iostream read more than specified

Tags: fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int argSiz;
    void* argBuf;
    std::fstream fStream;
    fStream.open("E:/Fts/Proj/Test/DFVisionConsole_Proj/DFVisionConsole/solution/DFDevDefault.dfv", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
    fStream.read((char*)&argSiz, 4);
    while(1)
    {
        long pos = fStream.tellg();
        fStream.read((char*)&argSiz, 4);
        long pos2 = fStream.tellg();
        argBuf = malloc(argSiz);
        fStream.read((char*)argBuf, argSiz);
        long pos3 = fStream.tellg();
        long mai = fStream.tellg();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When

```
fStream.read((char*)&argSiz, ETypebufSizeSize);//argSiz = 24103
long pos2 = fStream.tellg();//size2 = 130
```

then

```
long pos3 = fStream.tellg();//pos3 = 24247
```

It shouldn't be 24247, 130 + 24103 = 24233.

Why does fstream read more than specified ?

You can download the test file DFDevDefualt.dfv
https://sourceforge.net/projects/genericlist/files/?source=navbar

Please help.

Comment: carriage returns on windows, since you did not specify ios::binary?

Comment: My god, you right, I change arg2 to ios::binary, it goes well then. I don't even notice that because I take streaming in binary as default for years. Curse that code copier.